# Residue requirements of Rabin-Williams primes?

Tags: signature, rabin-cryptosystem, p1363

I'm trying to determine the residue requirements of Rabin-Williams. An older copy of [P1363's Public Key Cryptography](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~guilley/recherche/cryptoprocesseurs/ieee/00891000.pdf) states the following in Section 8.1.3.2 RW key pairs:

> An RW public key consists of a modulus n, which is the product of two
>   odd positive prime integers $p$ and $q$, such that $p\not≡q\pmod8$, and an
>   even public exponent $e\;$ ($2≤e<n$), which is an integer relatively
>   prime to $(p – 1)(q – 1)/4$. [Note that these conditions imply that
>   $p≡q≡3\pmod4$; moreover, one of the primes is congruent to $3\pmod8$
>   and the other is congruent to $7\pmod8$.]

I *think* Bernstein provides a survey of more relaxed conditions in [RSA signatures and Rabin–Williams signatures: the state of the art](http://cr.yp.to/sigs/rwsota-20080131.pdf). For example, in Section 4:

> State-of-the-art systems use exponent 2 rather than exponent 3. This
>   speeds up verification, and improves the signature-compression and
>   signature-expansion features discussed in subsequent sections. The
>   signer’s secret primes p and q are chosen from 3 + 4**Z** to simplify
>   signing.

Eventually, Bernstein converges on the IEEE P1363 paper (and then surpasses it in Section 6 when he forgoes Jacobi symbols).

What are the minimum requirements for *p* and *q* in Rabin-Williams? Is it *p*, *q* ∈ *3 + 4**Z***; or is it *p* ∈ *3 + 8**Z*** and *q* ∈ *7 + 8**Z***?

---

The practical problem I am facing is I don't know when to accept or reject a set of parameters during validation. I know *p*, *q* ∈ *3 + 4**Z*** is less efficient, but I'm not sure it's forbidden.

Comment: In " _minimum requirements_ " and " _I'm not sure it's forbidden_ ", the crucial point is: required/forbidden BY WHAT? A standard? A particular implementation (or definition) of RW? The feasibility of a working implementation (or definition) of RW using $p\;q$ as the public modulus?

Comment: @fgrieu - Right. If I am working with RW signatures in general, I think I can use *p, q ∈ 3 + 4**Z***. If I am working with RW signatures in P1363, I think I need to ensure *p % 8 != q %8*. Is that correct?

Comment: I was under the impression that the only _hard_ requirements were $p \ne q$, $p \equiv q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, and $p,q \in \mathbb P$. See section 4 in https://www.math.uzh.ch/aa/fileadmin/user/davide/publikation/AAECCrabin2014v11.pdf.